# Modify Column in Place based on Criteria

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
Class     Status    Species
Sands       D        Carex
Clay        C        Carex
Loam        D        Poapra
```

When `Status` is `D` and `Species` is Carex I want to change `Class` to `Wet`.  My desired output is:

```
Class     Status    Species
Wet         D        Carex
Clay        C        Carex
Loam        D        Poapra
```

I don't care if the answer is posted in pandas as I can still use it, but I really am trying to teach myself to loop in python right now.  If you know how to do this in both all the more welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pandas you can use `loc` to mask the df and pass the 2 boolean conditions wrapped in parentheses due to operator precedence as you have to use the `&` operator when comparing arrays:

```
In [233]:
df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'D') & (df['Species'] == 'Carex'), 'Class'] = 'Wet'
df

Out[233]:
  Class Status Species
0   Wet      D   Carex
1  Clay      C   Carex
2  Loam      D  Poapra
```